# HttpWebRequest.GetResponse. Unable to establish a connection to the server

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, system.net.webexception

I am using `HTTPWebRequest` in c# to connect to a server in a .netStandard project.

**Code.**

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

// Send request
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
request.CookieContainer = cookies;

Stream postData = request.GetRequestStream();

postData.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
postData.Close();

// Get and return response
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Stream Answer = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader answer = new StreamReader(Answer);
string ans = answer.ReadToEnd();
```

I am using the netstandard project in a UWP application. The server is IIS.
Now this code works when called from my machine to the server (my machine) using my private IP. 
When I change the machine that runs the app, and also the server (server is again, on the same machine as the app), I get

> System.Net.WebException: An error occurred while sending the request.
>   The text associated with this error code could not be found. A
>   connection with the server could not be established

I have checked that the Url is correct and it works when I do the post in `PostMan`. I also have enabled "`Private networks Client&Sever capabilities` on UWP app"
What could be the problem?

**Edit:**

> the inner exception is: " An error occurred while sending the request"
>
> Hresult:-2147012867
>
> Status:UnknownError

Comment: Is `WebException.InnerException` initialized?

Comment: Yes " An error occurred while sending the request"

Hresult:-2147012867

Status:UnknownError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to **Add loopback exemption** for the app. Because of network isolation, some UWP apps are restricted to use IP loopback addresses.

From Step 8 of [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/web-install-iis).

> Due to network isolation, UWP apps like App Installer are restricted
>   to use IP loopback addresses like http://localhost/. When using local
>   IIS Server, App Installer must be added to the loopback exempt list.

In my case I had to add loopback exemption for MY app.

1. Find out the app package name. It should be inside this folder %LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages
2. Open Command prompt as ADMIN
3. Check if the app is in the exemption list.
    `CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt -s`
4. If not, then : 
   `CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt -d -n="<your package name>"`
5. To confirm the exemption, execute step 3 again.